# 12.10 installation has taken 7.5 hours already

Tags: installation, 12.10, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 desktop 32-bit in VirtualBox 4.2.6 r82870 running under Windows Vista 64-bit. I'm installing from a DVD drive. The installation went fine up to the point where it said "Checking for packages to remove" but it has now been in that state for more than 7.5 hours, all the time thrashing the DVD drive. I can't believe this is normal. If I stop the installation, will I be able to complete it?

Comment: I feel Ubuntu is like Wine, the longer it takes to finish, the better. Just kidding, it might be related to Vista being the Host and Virtualbox. Also, in that part you are mentioning, you should have an option that says "Skip". Can you see the option?

Comment: You can't use wine unless Ubuntu is already running :-)

Comment: No, I couldn't see a skip option. After 12 hours I forced a dismount of the DVD drive and rebooted the VM. Ubuntu came up and appears to be working, although I wonder what's missing from the installation.

Answer (score 1):

install should take no more than 15 minutes. I'm pretty sure the install dvd has errors. When you burn your disc use the slowest speed setting and check if the md5sum is correct.

[Here are the md5sums for 12.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/MD5SUMS). Compare them to the md5sum of the iso on your installation disc. The one that's relevant to you is the one that ends with "desktop-i386.iso"

[This guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows) explains how to do it on windows

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are swapping windows style....In otherwords, you may not have sufficient memory to support both OSes within the same box.

Comment: The machine has 8Gb and I configured virtualbox to provide 2Gb to Ubuntu, even though it suggested only 384M